# JavaFX 2.x : Using StackPane to layer more different type charts

Tags: charts, javafx

Having this suggestion,

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2435573&tstart=0

I have tryed to use StackPane but second chart replace first one.

How to plot two or more different Chart (as in my example) in the same graph?

Here is my code

```
public class XyChartInSplitStackpane extends Application {
SplitPane               splitPane1 = null;
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
stage.setTitle("Line plot");

final CategoryAxis xAxis1 = new CategoryAxis();
final NumberAxis yAxis1 = new NumberAxis();

yAxis1.setTickUnit(1);
yAxis1.setPrefWidth(35);
yAxis1.setMinorTickCount(10);

yAxis1.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis1){
    @Override
public String toString(Number object){
        String label;
        label = String.format("%7.2f", object.floatValue());
        return label;
}
});
final BarChart<String, Number>barChart1 = new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis1, yAxis1);

barChart1.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
barChart1.setLegendVisible(false);
barChart1.setAnimated(false);

XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();

series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 1));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 2));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 1.5));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 3));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 2.5));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 5));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 4));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 8));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 6.5));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 13));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 10));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 20));

barChart1.getData().addAll(series1); 

final CategoryAxis xAxis2 = new CategoryAxis();
final NumberAxis yAxis2 = new NumberAxis(1, 21,0.1);

yAxis2.setTickUnit(1);
yAxis2.setPrefWidth(35);
yAxis2.setMinorTickCount(10);

yAxis2.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis2){
    @Override
public String toString(Number object){
        String label;
        label = String.format("%7.2f", object.floatValue());
        return label;
}
});
final LineChart<String, Number>lineChart2 = new LineChart<String, Number>(xAxis2,  yAxis2);

lineChart2.setCreateSymbols(false);
lineChart2.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
lineChart2.setLegendVisible(false);
lineChart2.setAnimated(false);

XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();

series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 2));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 10));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 8));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 4));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 7));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 5));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 4));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 8));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 16.5));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 13.9));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 17));
series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 10));

Set<Node> nodes1 = barChart1.lookupAll(".series0");    
for (Node n: nodes1) {        
    n.setStyle("-fx-blend-mode:  src-over");        
}

lineChart2.getData().addAll(series2);
Set<Node> nodes2 = lineChart2.lookupAll(".series0");    
for (Node n: nodes2) {        
    n.setStyle("-fx-stroke: red; -fx-background-color: red, white; -fx-blend-mode: src-over; -fx-opacity: 0.5");
}    

splitPane1 = new SplitPane();   
StackPane stackpane = new StackPane();
stackpane.getChildren().add(barChart1);                
stackpane.getChildren().add(lineChart2);

splitPane1.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
splitPane1.getItems().addAll(stackpane);    
splitPane1.setDividerPosition(0, 1);

Scene scene = new Scene(splitPane1, 800, 600);

stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see your adding the `series` to two different charts

ie. 
`lineChart2.getData().addAll(series2);` & `barChart1.getData().addAll(series1);`

However if this is intentional all you need to do to add the other data to one of the charts is to simply use: `barChart1.getData().addAll(series1, series2);`